# Исключение java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

При запуске этого метода

```
public void updateProgressBar() {
        progressBarHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = 0;
            try {
                totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long currentDuration = 0;
            try {
                currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            songTotalDurationLabel.setText(
                    "" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(
                    "" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));


            int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                    totalDuration));

            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            progressBarHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

        }
    };
```

---

В LogCat'e появляется ошибка:

```
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at ru.vspr.MyMediaPlayerActivity$100000000.run(MyMediaPlayerActivity.java:155)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-25 10:22:00.658 E/AndroidRuntime( 4913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 10:22:06.258 E/InputDispatcher(  148): channel '41316928 Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

**UPD:** Вопрос закрыт, т.к. проблема была решена добавлением

```
Utilities utils = new Utilisies();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой вам совет.

1. Откройте студию и включите в ней - показывать номера строк.
2. Дважды нажмите на ru.vspr.MyMediaPlayerActivity$100000000.run(MyMediaPlayerActivity.java:155)
3. Откройте MyMediaPlayerActivity и тажмите Ctrl+L и перейдите на 155 строку. Там у вас есть переменная которая не определена.

Comment: Подскажите, как и где определить переменную.
А то у меня выводит ошибку an instance of type android.widget.TextView cannot be assigned to (int)

Answer (score 2):

НЯП, это код класса `MyMediaPlayerActivity`.

В этом классе есть переменные - члены класса `mediaPlayer`, `utils`, `songTotalDurationLabel`, `songProgressBar`. Одну из них Вы не определили. Она `null`.

Перепроверьте.